# Как задать переменную PHP через форму?

Tags: php

Как можно сделать так чтобы на странице в браузере можно было бы ввести цифровую переменную, чтобы она потом уже в коде была задана?

---

```
function getPassword() { // Возвращает валидный пароль $password = getRandomPassword(); $length = 16; do { $password = getRandomPassword(); } while(iconv_strlen($password, 'UTF-8') != $length); return $password; }
```

В переменную $lenth нужно вводить все время число, так как она задает длинну возвращаемого пароля

Comment: Приведите абстрактный пример. Не понятно, что вы хотите сделать и зачем.

Comment: Смотрите в сторону $_GET и $_POST

Comment: Есть специальная функция [extract](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.extract.php)